# Drupal 7 Webforms 4, prevent submission if value of field is less than or equal to previous submission

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I know that you can prevent submission if a specific value has previously submitted.

However can you prevent a submission if the submission is less than or equal to a previously submitted value.

example, you have a an existing value if 16.00 in the results. So you can not submit 0.00-16.00